# ARG for folder path not working

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

This works:

```
COPY Subfolder/ /inetpub/wwwroot
```

This copies the ENTIRE working directory (not just the Subfolder)

```
ARG site_root="Subfolder/"
# ARG site_root="Subfolder/" # this doesnt work either
# ARG site_root=Subfolder/ # this doesnt work either
# ARG site_root=./Subfolder # this doesnt work either
# ARG site_root=.Subfolder/ # this doesnt work either
# ARG site_root=Subfolder # this doesnt work either
COPY ${site_root} /inetpub/wwwroot
```

How do I use the subdir path in a var?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For me, only the contents of `Subfolder` are copied into the destination folder. Just one question - is `Subfolder` within the build context (within the directory tree that has the Dockerfile at it's root)?